# Vorlonjs on https

Tags: debugging, https, vorlon

I am trying to use vorlonjs inside a angular app. I installed and followed all the steps in the documentation as they were presented, but in chrome dev-tools I get a connection refused error( http://localhost:1337/vorlon.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED), when I am loading main page.

Is this a known issue or I need to do other configuration for it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you access to the http://localhost:1337/vorlon.js script from your browser ?

VorlonJS and your angular app are running on the same server ?

Answer (score 1):

To be sure, have you followed all the steps listed at https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/Vorlonjs#ssl-support? Can you provide more details if the issue isn't resolved yet? 
(We can push the issue to the Vorlon Github repo if you find something.)